# How to find the time when wave altitude rapidly changes in matlab?

Tags: matlab, signals

I have EEG data as can be seen in the attached image.

As you can see, there is a time that wave altitude suddenly increases and then decreases after a while. I am looking for the time (horizontal axis) when the wave increase and decreases.

I have shown those areas in the attached image by Red, Green, and Purple color.

Note: I am not an expert in either signal processing or EEG data analysis. Could you explain it in a simple way?

[EEG Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AZxW.png)

Answer (score 0):

The matlab function `findpeaks` may fit your needs. Without data, we cannot help you more than this: try `help findpeaks`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a picker to detect the points of sudden increase. A common approach is the short term average over long term average picker (STA/LTA) which detects (picks) when this value exceeds a threshold. This would give you the onset, if you then flip your signal in time and do the picking again you can get the end of your bursts. Here is an implementation of the STA/LTA picker

https://github.com/bpostlethwaite/Masters-Thesis/blob/master/matlab/sourceStack/stalta.m